# Problems with Android Studio and Cocoapods

Tags: kotlin, cocoapods, version, multiplatform, podfile

I´m complete new to Android Studio with multiplatform projects and Kotlin.
Actually I´m wondering because of two things.
After writing the logic in Kotlin shared/src/commonMain/... I wanted to test it by writing an Activity on the Android part. I made a new one in shared/src/AndroidMain/... by rightclick on the folder.
The new Activity has been generated in shared/src/Main/... - a new folder hirachy. Why??

After that, my gradle.build in shared/ cannot be synced anymore. I´m getting the error:

> Cocoapods Integration requires pod version to be specified.
> Please specify pod version by adding 'version = ""' to the cocoapods block.
> Alternatively, specify the version for the entire project explicitly.
> Pod version format has to conform podspec syntax requirements: https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#version

I´ve put 'version="1.0"' on every part of the gradle files where it could be right but the message still remains.
Can anybody explain me excactly where to put the version number? I´ve read a lot of pages, saying all the same but nothing works for my project.

Here my shared/build.gradle.kts

```
plugins {
    kotlin("multiplatform")
    id("org.jetbrains.gradle.apple.applePlugin") version "212.4638.14-0.13.1"
    //kotlin("native.cocoapods")
    id ("org.jetbrains.kotlin.native.cocoapods")
    id("com.android.library")
    id ("com.google.gms.google-services")
    kotlin("plugin.serialization")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")

}

version = "1.0"

kotlin {
    android()
    iosX64()
    iosArm64()
    iosSimulatorArm64()

    cocoapods {
        version = "1.0"
        summary = "Some description for the Shared Module"
        homepage = "Link to the Shared Module homepage"
        ios.deploymentTarget = "14.1"
        podfile = project.file("../iosApp/Podfile")
        framework {
            baseName = "shared"
        }
        specRepos {
            url("https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlin-cocoapods-spec.git")
        }
        pod("FirebaseAuth")
    }
    
    sourceSets {
        val commonMain by getting{
            dependencies{
                implementation("dev.gitlive:firebase-database:1.6.1")
                implementation ("dev.gitlive:firebase-auth:1.6.1")
                implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-json:1.4.0-RC")
            }
            version = "1.0"
        }
        val commonTest by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(kotlin("test"))
            }
        }
        val androidMain by getting
        val androidTest by getting
        val iosX64Main by getting
        val iosArm64Main by getting
        val iosSimulatorArm64Main by getting
        val iosMain by creating {
            dependsOn(commonMain)
            iosX64Main.dependsOn(this)
            iosArm64Main.dependsOn(this)
            iosSimulatorArm64Main.dependsOn(this)
            version = "1.0"
        }
        val iosX64Test by getting
        val iosArm64Test by getting
        val iosSimulatorArm64Test by getting
        val iosTest by creating {
            dependsOn(commonTest)
            iosX64Test.dependsOn(this)
            iosArm64Test.dependsOn(this)
            iosSimulatorArm64Test.dependsOn(this)
        }
    }
}

android {
    compileSdk = 32
    sourceSets["main"].manifest.srcFile("src/androidMain/AndroidManifest.xml")
    defaultConfig {
        minSdk = 27
        targetSdk = 32
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding = true
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}

dependencies{
    implementation("dev.gitlive:firebase-database:1.6.1")
    implementation ("dev.gitlive:firebase-auth:1.6.1")
    implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0")
    implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.0")
    implementation("androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4")
    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.5")
    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.3.5")
    //implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-json:1.4.0-RC")
}
```

Any help would be highly appreciated :-)

Platform Windows 11
AndroidStudio 2021.2.1 Patch 2
Kotlin 1.7.10